# I have day,month and year in integer. So now I want to convert it to String in java (version 7)

Tags: java

I have ::

```
int day = 6;
int month = 2;
int year = 2020;
```

So I want it as "Thu 6 February 2020" in java without using Locale Date class because Local Date class is not available in Java 7.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `LocalDate` class? That class is meant for this kind of thing. You first construct a `LocalDate` object, then you format it to a string using a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: You will have to figure out which day of the week correlates to to the day int in a specific month. You may have to write a formula, day 1, month 1 = Wed, and calculate every other day based on knowing the one day. It will get more complicated as you get into leap/non leap years

Comment: Excuse me, your requirement is absurd. *I want to knock a nail in, but I don’t want to use a hammer.* What do you want to use? Or is it a homework requirement, and if so, what are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 1):

You should define arrays for days and months names:

```
String[] daysNames = {"", "SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"};
String[] monthsNames = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

Then you can use Calendar class to get the right Day of week:

```
int day = 6;
int month = 2;
int year = 2020;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

String dayOfWeek = daysNames[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)];

String data = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s %d %s %d", dayOfWeek, day, monthsNames[month], year);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to avoid the `LocalDate` class. That class is meant for this kind of thing. Anyway, here's how you do it with it:

```
int day = 6;
int month = 2;
int year = 2020;

LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd MMMM yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

String result = date.format(formatter);
System.out.println(result); // Prints Thu 6 February 2020
```

Comment: I cannot use Local Date class because it is not available in Java 7. The solution you have given is simple and I already knew about that but I am using Java 7. You should not just simply close someone's question

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `LocalDate` or others java8 time utils, you could try `Calendar` class. Also to format it the way you want you can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, day);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy");
System.out.println(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

You have to do `month - 1` since months are counted from `0`

Answer (score 1):

To get the day of the week by a date you would have to create a system which starts at a specific date and 'counts' upwards after this date.
This can be very annoying regarding leap-years and the different amount of days per month.

(You clearly stated you are not interested in LocalDate but I still advice it)